# Mastering Custom ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

[ScrollView http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3216968/ScrollView%20problem.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3216968/ScrollView%20problem.png)

I have a ScrollView that contains a LinearLayout. I have two customizations I want to implement.

[1]
How to I remove the black shadow on the top?
Tried to look at [Why is my List black Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html?m=1) but that is only for the ListView and talking about the background.

[2]
When I try to make a shake animation for the LinearLayout the animation is not showing outside the lines. Have tried so many different things and are beginning think is not possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ScrollView_response"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:fadingEdge="none" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_response"
    android:background="@drawable/background_red"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="270dp"

    >
```

This is the Activity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.manual_resonse_layout);

    Animation shakeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake_in);
    LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_response);

    mainView.startAnimation(shakeIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the "black shadow" on top, setting the ScrollView android:fadingEdge XML attribute to "none" should do.

Answer (score 0):

In order that shake animation works, your linear layout need to have some margins set so that it has enough "room" to shake around. You can make your scroll view to fill the width of the screen and the linear layout smaller and placed in the middle etc.

As for the shadow, that is a good question!

Comment: made the linear layout wrapping the content and added a 30dp margin.. still no luck..

Comment: The view animation is limited by its parent window, you need to be sure that the child view does not entirely fill the parent. You may have a margin but if the content of LinearLayout_response streaches it to fill the parent it may not work. You can make sure that your animation works properly by testing it on a view which is in the middle of a realtiveLayout etc. Try setting gravity of the scrollView to centre. Finally the view animations do not seem to work always as expected in my experince so you need to experiment ;)